# need to calculate #quarters for which product was not bought continuously

Tags: excel, vba

[image: sample record]

Please refer to the image.

I have records of the buying trends of customers across 20 quarters in terms of revenue. I want to calculate the gaps for each customer i.e. #quarters for which revenue was 0 continuously. Also, I need to calculate the maximum size of the gaps for each customer.

For this specific record, there are 2 gaps in revenues. One b/w 2015Q1 and 2016Q1 and another between 2016Q4 and 2017Q3. I need a code/logic to be able to calculate these 2 gaps of 3 quarters and 2 quarters respectively and then the max of those gaps.

I tried using match index, but it seemed to not help achieve the desired outcome. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Do you need to find the position and length of each gap separately, as well as the maximum length? I ask because it should be possible to find the max length in one step.

Comment: To clarify, I need to find #gaps, length of each gap and the maximum length among the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm unsure of how you want the results formatted but I'll assume it will be 2 cells to the right of the info you have above, 1 for the # of gaps and 1 to show the maximum GAP. The below code should be able to assist but changes will have to be made based on the amount of rows/columns being checked.

```
   Sub Finder()

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim GapCounter As Integer
Dim MaxCounter As Integer

'This For statement should be change according to how many rows need to be done
For c = 2 To 3

GapCounter = 0
MaxCounter = 0

'This For statement should be changed according to how many columns are being viewed.
For Y = 1 To 11

'This will check to see if the next column is a 0, if so a gap is beginning and the gap counter will increase
If Cells(c, Y).Value <> 0 And Cells(c, Y + 1).Value = 0 And IsEmpty(Cells(c, Y + 1)) = False Then GapCounter = GapCounter + 1

'This is checking value,if value is 0 need to add it to the current Gap amount
If Cells(c, Y).Value = 0 Then MaxCounter = MaxCounter + 1

'Checks to see if the next value is not a 0 and is not empty, if these are met we can conclude that's all the gap that needs to be counted and compare to the previous Max gap #, if it's larger than we replace
'Then we have to reset the max counter
If Cells(c, Y + 1).Value <> 0 And IsEmpty(Cells(c, Y + 1)) = False And MaxCounter > Cells(c, 14).Value Then
'This is the cell where the max time a gap has lasted will appear.
Cells(c, 14).Value = MaxCounter
MaxCounter = 0
End If

Next
'This is the cell where the # of gaps will appear
Cells(c, 13).Value = GapCounter

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Randayor !  To clarify, I need to find length of each gap as well as the maximum length among the gaps.

Comment: Can you just help me with the code for calculating the length of all the gaps? In the above case, I need to get the value of both the gaps of 3 quarters and 2 quarters.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how you want the results to be displayed in excel? Do you just want the # of gaps in one cell and then next to it a cell that just says 3,2,......indicating the varying lengths of the gaps?